# Logging requests coming to endpoint in my Web App in production

Tags: c#, .net

I have an application that uses an external registrar.  This is a .Net Framework application hosted on Azure that I am in the process of upgrading to .Net Core.  The registrar provides users with an email containing a confirmation link - which leads to my app.  The request generated by this link is supposed to contain a number of guid string parameters which identify the user, the course etc.

My problem is that about 10% of the requests from these links that I am getting from the registrar contain integers or number strings for some of the parameters - instead of the Guid strings - especially for the clinic_id that identifies the course to be taken.

This is what the controller capturing the requests looks like:

```
[Route("hcr/{clinic_id}/{clinic_attendee_id}/{member_id}/{organisation_id}/{first_name}")]
    [HttpGet]
    public async Task<ActionResult> ProcessHcrRegistration(string clinic_id, string clinic_attendee_id, string member_id, string organisation_id, string first_name)
    {
        HcrPackage hcrPackage = CreateHcrPackage(clinic_id, clinic_attendee_id, member_id, organisation_id, first_name);

        var duplicateExists = await DuplicateEnrollmentExists(clinic_attendee_id);

        if (duplicateExists)
        {
            return RedirectToAction("Index", "MyCourses");
       }_context.HcrPackages.Add(hcrPackage);
        await _context.SaveChangesAsync();
```

How can I trap and log the exact content of the requests to my app - which is in production so that I can get to the bottom of this problem?

Comment: Are we talking about some REST Web-API hosted in Azure? Is it writing logs to AppInsights? If so, you can activate Request logging.